# The review page has outdated counters

Tags: bug, review, caching

When I go to review page I get something like this(enabled questions/answers for review):

> [image]

But then I click for example on "First Posts" I get:

> There are no items for you to review.

I'm trying to understand the behavior of this "broken" page and found that counters are enabled after 2-3 minutes then posts/answers are enabled for review.

P.S. I'm using VPN, but all other sites works fine(without delay)

Comment: I'd be willing to hedge my bet on server side caching.